# How to sort reverse array in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

How can I reverse the order in which I perform a for loop?
I would like to stop the modules in reverse order

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
declare -a modules
mapfile -t modules < /app/appscripts/jenkins_modules
#jenkins_modules is txt file which consist string 01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw

for module in ${modules[@]} 
do
baseDir=/app/${module} # here is my script stopping modules
if [ -d ${baseDir} ]
then
    pushd ${baseDir}
    echo "Stopping module: ${module}\n"
    #./stop.sh ${baseDir}
    echo "Module: ${module} stopped\n"
    popd
  fi
done
```

I tried to reverse the sort in a loop, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
declare -a modules
mapfile -t modules < /app/appscripts/jenkins_modules
#jenkins_modules is txt file which consist string 01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw

for (( module=${#modules[@]}-1 ; module>=0 ; module-- ));
do
baseDir=/app/${module} # here script stopping modules
if [ -d ${baseDir} ]
then
    pushd ${baseDir}
    echo "Stopping module: ${module}\n"
    #./stop.sh ${baseDir}
    echo "Module: ${module} stopped\n"
    popd
  fi
done
```

I also try sort -rn.
Modules are displayed but are not sorted reverse

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
declare -a modules
mapfile -t modules < /app/appscripts/jenkins_modules
#jenkins_modules is txt file which consist string 01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw

for module in ${modules[@]| sort -rn}
do
baseDir=/app/${module} # here is my script stopping modules
if [ -d ${baseDir} ]
then
    pushd ${baseDir}
    echo "Stopping module: ${module}\n"
    #./stop.sh ${baseDir}
    echo "Module: ${module} stopped\n"
    popd
  fi
done
```

Comment: This might help: [Bash - reverse an array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412868/74329)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
declare -a modules
mapfile -t modules < /app/appscripts/jenkins_modules
for (( i = 1; i <= "${#modules[@]}"; ++i )); do       # if you have 25 modules, is 1 .. 25
  (( j = -i ))                                        # j is -1 .. -25
  printf "%s\n" "${modules[$j]}"
done
```

```
$ declare -a modules=()
$ modules=( foo{1..5} )
$ printf "%s\n" "${modules[@]}"            # TIP: printf automatically loops if given too many arguments
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
$ printf "%s\n" "${modules[@]}" | tail -r  # TIP `tail -r` reverses the lines of its input
foo5
foo4
foo3
foo2
foo1
$ for (( i = 1; i <= "${#modules[@]}"; ++i )); do  # i takes on values 1 thru 5
> (( j = -i ))                                     # j takes on values -1 (last) to -5 (5th from last)
> printf "%s\n" "${modules[$j]}"
> done
foo5
foo4
foo3
foo2
foo1
```

Answer (score -1):

In your C-style loop, `module` isn't an element of the array; it's just an index:

```
for (( i=${#modules[@]}-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- ));
do
  module=${modules[i]}
  baseDir=/app/${module} # here script stopping modules
  if [ -d ${baseDir} ]
  then
    pushd ${baseDir}
    echo "Stopping module: ${module}\n"
    #./stop.sh ${baseDir}
    echo "Module: ${module} stopped\n"
    popd
  fi
done
```

However, it might be worth simply building the array in reverse order in the first place, rather than using `mapfile`:

```
modules=()
while IFS= read -r module; do
  modules=("$module" "${modules[@]}")
done < /app/appscripts/jenkins_modules

...

for module in "${modules[@]}"; do
  baseDir=/app/$module
  [[ -d "$baseDir" ]] || continue
  pushd "$baseDir"
  ...
  popd
done
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use the `modules=("$module" "${modules[@]}")` rather than the `modules+=("$module")` syntax, or that you prefer a `read` loop rather than `read -a` or `mapfile`?

Comment: `+=` would append the value to the array; I want to prepend the value so that the array is built in reverse order, negating the need to iterate over it in reverse.

Comment: After debugging I receive 1st: `+ set -e
+ declare -a modules
+ mapfile -t modules
+ (( i=1-1  ))
+ (( i>=0  ))
+ module='01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw'
+ baseDir='/app/01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw'
+ '[' -d '/app/01_docker 02_gtw 99_mq_gtw' ']'
+ (( i--  ))
+ (( i>=0  ))
+ set +x`

Comment: Second `+ modules=()
+ IFS=
+ read -r module
+ for module in '"$modules[@]}"'
+ baseDir='/app/[@]}'
+ [[ -d /app/[@]} ]]
+ continue
+ set +x`